# Calling the cognito hostedUI /oauth2/authorize login endpoint returns unauthorized_client error when calling from ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

**Problem Description:** Calling the AWS Cognito Hosted UI endpoint /oauth2/authorize does not work when routing from a reactJS app deployed as a amplify app. Everything was working when I had a basic index.html page (with no reactJS) deployed on aws cloudfront/s3 with amplify app, but when I changed the webapp code to reactJS, I start getting the `unauthorized_client` error response from cognito /oauth2/authorize endpoint. I've tried to change my reactJS code to have  as well (similar to basic index.html), but I get the same error.

NOTE: I am not using the amplify npm libraries, and keeping the app very basic by calling the cognito hosted UI endpoint directly.

> ReactJS app Code

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Logout from './pages/Logout';
import {Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <div className='container'>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
          <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**/pages/Home.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <div>
        <a href="https://<myapp>.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<my-client_id>&response_type=code&scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmain.<myamplifyapp>.amplifyapp.com">
          <button>Login</button>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <a href="https://<myapp>.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/logout?client_id=<my-client_id>&response_type=code&scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmain.<myamplifyapp>.amplifyapp.com">
          <button>Logout</button>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

**/pages/Login.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const Login = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      {/* <a href="https://<myapp>.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<my-client_id>&response_type=code&scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmain.<myamplifyapp>.amplifyapp.com"> */}
        <button onClick={routeToCognitoLogin}>Login</button>
      {/* </a> */}
    </div>
  )
}

function routeToCognitoLogin(){
  window.location.replace("https://<myapp>.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<my-client_id>&response_type=code&scope=aws.cognito.signin.user.admin&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmain.<myamplifyapp>.amplifyapp.com")
}

export default Login
```

Action: Clicking on the Login button should route to cognito, but I get a error from cognito.

> ***Inspecting the page on Chrome dev tool***
> [image: Inspecting the error as hosted UI login page did not load on Chrome dev tool]